# how to dynamically calculate sum of increases?

Tags: matrix, apl, dyalog

I have the following data:

```
a b c d
5 9 6 0
3 1 3 2
```

Characters in the first row, numbers in the 2nd and 3rd rows.

How can I change the second row depending on the numbers in row 3?

For example, in the 3rd row, if the number is 3, then the corresponding number in row 2 is multiplied by 2, and if in the 3rd row the number is 1, then add 3 to the number in row 2:

```
a  b  c  d
10 12 12 0
3  1  3  2
```

Also, how do I dynamically calculate the sum of these increases?

Dyalog APL 17.0+

Comment: I have some questions 1. What if the number is neither 1 not 3 then what to do? 2. In output what you want? Updated second row or value by it's increased by? 3. What is 17+ mean here?

Comment: if number not 1 and not 3 need do nothing. In the output need just print upd row with changed numbers and not changed. and i want see number by which the second row increased

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I've clarified that "17+" refers to [Dyalog APL 17.0](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Dyalog_APL_versions#17.0) or newer.

Comment: @cickness You might be interested in frequenting [the Stack Exchange APL chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard?_=1620076451), where you'll find both beginner and expert APLers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a multiplier vector and an addition vector from the condition masks.

`n⌷data` gets you the `n`th row a `data` matrix.

The columns of the second row that you want to double are indicated by:

```
      3=3⌷data
1 0 1 0
```

So the multiplication vector is:

```
      1+3=3⌷data
2 1 2 1
```

The columns of the second row that you want to add 3 to are:

```
      1=3⌷data
0 1 0 0
```

So the addition vector is:

```
      3×1=3⌷data
0 3 0 0
```

The new second row is thus:

```
      (3×1=3⌷data)+(1+3=3⌷data)×2⌷data
10 12 12 0
```

We can express this as a dyadic function taking the 3rd row as left argument (the control) and the second row as right argument (the actual data):

```
      Update←{(3×1=⍺)+(1+3=⍺)×⍵}
      (3⌷data) Update (2⌷data)
10 12 12 0
```

Now we can either create a new matrix with the updated values:

```
      (3⌷data) Update@2 ⊢data
 a  b  c d
10 12 12 0
 3  1  3 2
```

Or do the replacement in-place:

```
      (2⌷data) Update⍨← (3⌷data)
      data
 a  b  c d
10 12 12 0
 3  1  3 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBCmJJYmP2iYYK5g86t2inqiuoJ4ExMlAnKKuYKpgqWCmYKBgrGAIxEZcoQVA5alA5dUaxoenG9o@6t2lqa1hqG0MZh2e/qh3ay2XhvGjnu0gYzUVIOodjBQedS0CiXDp6upyaRihyT/qXQE0UgGhjwtEAgA)

---

Note that your algorithms would be simplified and your code run faster if you kept data with different roles in separate variables. For example:

```
      (keys values control)←↓data
      control Update values
10 12 12 0
      values Update⍨← control
      values
10 12 12 0
      ↑keys values control
 a  b  c d
10 12 12 0
 3  1  3 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNmplcUKQPCobYKCeqK6gnoSECcDcYo6V1liTmlqMUROwRSoyBKIzYDYgCs5P6@kKD8HImUMFDJUgNBGXKEFKYklqUCJag3jw9MNbR/17tLU1jDUNgazDk9/1Lu1Fq4folgBYhOXrq4uzFKoKb0rQDZAVXMhKXvUNhHsdKhyqAoA)

---

The sum of the increases is simply the sum of the differences between the new values and the original values:

```
      +/values-⍨control Update values
14
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNmplcUKQPCobYKCeqK6gnoSECcDcYo6V1liTmlqMUROwRSoyBKIzYDYgCs5P6@kKD8HImUMFDJUgNBGXKEFKYklqUCJag3jw9MNbR/17tLU1jDUNgazDk9/1Lu1lktbH2K47qPeFTCzIBoVIBIA)

Answer (score 0):

In NARS2000 (I don't know if is ok for other APL compilers too),
"⍵[2;],¨⍵[3;]" make couples of 2 rows of ⍵, the row n.2 and the row n.3.

```
  f←{(a b)←⍵⋄b=3:2×a⋄b=1:a+3⋄a}
  h←{3 4⍴⍵[1;],(f¨⍵[2;],¨⍵[3;]),⍵[3;]}
  B←3 4⍴'abcd',5 9 6 0 3 1 3 2
  ⎕fmt B
┌4───────┐
3 a b c d│
│ 5 9 6 0│
│ 3 1 3 2│
└+───────┘
  ⎕fmt h B
┌4──────────┐
3  a  b  c d│
│ 10 12 12 0│
│  3  1  3 2│
└+──────────┘
```